# How does Django detect locale to make translation work

Tags: django

I don't quite understand how Django detect the local machine's locale. I have made the translation works if I explicitly set the language code. But how does it make translation base on locale and how to test it.

Comment: Have you set `USE_L10N=True` in your settings and do you have `django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware` in your middleware?

Comment: yes. I did that.

Answer (score 0):

[Here are the Django docs that describe the process in detail](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/i18n/translation/#how-django-discovers-language-preference)

Comment: How do I test it?